# Is this how to say Steph Curry in American sign language

Tags: language

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/sportsnation/status/601749481038688257) (retweeted over 2300 times) makes a claim about how to say "Steph Curry" in American sign language:

[image]

Is that claim true?

Comment: I don't think this is notable. It is pretty clearly a joke given the context, and is not likely to be sincerely believed by many people.

Comment: @nomenagentis: ASL is much less homogenized/standardized than English. There are large variations between signs for many common English words, and name signs tend to be pretty local. I know Obama has a name sign, but I haven't seen anyone use it. Finger-spelling is the typical way to sign a name; letter by letter. So, even if that *is* Steph Curry's name sign, very few people would use it. More likely than not to be a joke, as Sean Duggan answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sign can mean "[very tall](http://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-signs/t/tall.htm)" in ASL if made above head height. Otherwise, names in ASL are either spelled out via fingersigning (if unknown) or represented with an identifying [shorthand sign](http://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-layout/namesigns.htm) (if known).

So, in short, this is almost certainly a joke, possibly about his [shooting technique](http://www.basketballworkouttips.com/wp-content/uploads/stephen-curry-shooting.jpg), especially since Sports Nation [made the same joke in March](https://www.facebook.com/sportsnation/photos/a.10153145966951100.1073741835.94471021099/10153145966676100/).

Comment: Handshape doesn't look right for the tall sign to me. Judging by the twitter reponses, foes seem more likely a reference to the peculiarity of how the player shoots.

Comment: @femtoRgon: You're right. I've added as much to my answer.